# c# columns names from ilist

Tags: c#, .net, list

This may be really simple. I have created a class with a list

```
public class lstLog
{
    public String column1;
    public String column2;
    public String column3;
    public String column4;
    // Methods
    public lstLog(String column1, String column2, String column3, String column4)
    {
        this.column1 = column1;
        this.column2 = column2;
        this.column3 = column3;
        this.column4 = column4;

    }
```

I can insert and read the contents of the list at runtime.
I would also like to get the column names at runtime.  Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Where does the list come into it?

Comment: And which column names - the values you've stored? The names of the column1-4 properties? Something else?

Comment: I'm not entirely following. You mean you want this array `{ "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4" }` ?

Comment: ... and when you say IList do you mean the untyped, not-generic one, or the typed `IList<lstLog>`? Is that related - you've got `object` s and you don't know how to convert them back to lstLogs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a dictionary so you can query columns by name and add/insert new ones as needed.

```
public class LstLog
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> columnDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // Methods
    public LstLog(String column1, String column2, String column3, String column4)
    {
        columnDictionary["column1"] = column1;
        columnDictionary["column2"] = column1;
        columnDictionary["column3"] = column1;
        columnDictionary["column4"] = column1;
    }
    public string GetColumnValue(string columnName)
    {
        if(columnDictionary.ContainsKey(columnName)
            return columnDictionary[columnName];
        else 
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: with a few changes this gave me exactly what i need.  I was looking for a way to do macro substituion and this gives me the closest thing to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retreive the name of the fields, you should use reflection.

Comment: can you give me an example plz

Answer (score 0):

You've got a "list" of variables, but a real list would look like this:

```
public List<string> _someStringList = new List<string>;
```

To get a list with something like columnnames you can use a dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> _someDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
```

To get the Names of your class you can use Reflection like this:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(lstLog).GetProperties())
  Console.WriteLine("A property with name: " pi.Name);
```